# how do I fix kibana timestamp

Tags: kibana

On my Kibana "discover" page, timestamps appear as "`2022-07-Th 18:21:00.234`" (Th for Thursday rather than 21st of the month).

Under Stack Mgmt --> advance settings, the format is `DD.MM.YY @ HH:mm:ss.SSS`, so I can't see where the problem lies.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is another place where formats can be defined, under "Stack Management" --> "Index Patterns". The problematic format was defined there, so I corrected it and the problem was solved.